# Nodejs Express server Cannot find module 'pdf-fill-form'

Tags: node.js, pdf

I'm really new to NodeJS and ExpressJS.

This is nodeJS RestAPI service.

In my project, I have to populate a PDF form field, To do that I wanted to get help from a nodejs library "pdf-fill-form" link ->https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form

I ran 'npm install pdf-fill-form' on my project folder terminal

Import it as in the example -> const pdfFillForm = require('pdf-fill-form');

But it throws an error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pdf-fill-form'
```

I have tried multiple libraries same issue came 'Cannot find module "Lib Name"'

Can someone who is an expert on Node JS help me?
Probably I have done something wrong, I did search for solutions but could not find any.

My Package json

```
{
  "name": "pemsbackend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TB",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "MyTest TB",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you placed `pdf-fill-form` in you're `package.json`

Comment: Now I added it Under 'dependencies'. and ran npm install on the terminal Stil same iisue

Comment: in you're updated question i don't see `pdf-fill-form` as dependency ?

Comment: I think 'npm install pdf-fill-form' automatically update package.json If everything went well with the command. Isn't it?

Comment: if you run npm command with `-S` flag then it will update the `package.json`

Comment: has anyone tried this on Windows? In docs it says that it is not supported - https://github.com/tpisto/pdf-fill-form#windows

Answer (score 1):

`pdf-fill-form` has other dependencies to be installed in you're system before installing it. Go through installing guide mentioned int it's [repo](https://github.com/tpisto/pdf-fill-form#installation) and then try installing it.